# Can you say "it's not mine" when you dislike something?

Tags: expressions

And what are other alternatives expressing that you personally don't like something? 

Context:
"- Hey, you've been living in Berlin for 3 months already! How is your German?
- I didn't learn it much. I feel like it's not my language"

Answer (score 4):

Two suitable idiomatic phrases I am aware of are **it's not for me** and **it's not me**.

The first case describes something as not conforming with the speaker's preferences. This is useful for the example like the one you gave:

> Hey, you've been living in Berlin for 3 months already! How is your German?
>
> I didn't learn it much. The German culture is not for me.

The second case can be used to say one is not "the type of person who would do that". (Another idiom that can be used here is "it's not who I am".) In an example like yours, it might be used like this:

> Hey, you've been living in Berlin for 3 months already! How is your German?
>
> I didn't learn it much. The German language is commanding and harsh sounding. It's not me.

(Apologies to Germanophiles!)

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression you're looking for is **not one's cup of tea**. According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-be-sb-s-cup-of-tea):

> "If **something is not your cup of tea**, it is not the type of thing of that you like"[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-be-sb-s-cup-of-tea)

**Attribution**
[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-be-sb-s-cup-of-tea) Not be sb's cup of tea Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary. (n.d.). Retrieved March 22, 2018, from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-be-sb-s-cup-of-tea